# Accuracy matrics isn't working on linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, regression, linear-regression

Kindly help here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [[1.1],[1.3],[1.5],[2],[2.2],[2.9],[3],[3.2],[3.2],[3.7],[3.9],[4],[4],[4.1],[4.5],[4.9],[5.1],[5.3],[5.9],[6],[6.8],[7.1],[7.9],[8.2],[8.7],[9],[9.5],[9.6],[10.3],[10.5]]
y = [39343,46205,37731,43525,39891,56642,60150,54445,64445,57189,63218,55794,56957,57081,61111,67938,66029,83088,81363,93940,91738,98273,101302,113812,109431,105582,116969,112635,122391,121872]


#implement the dataset for train & test

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 1/3,random_state=0)

#implement our classifier based on Simple Linear Regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
SimpleLinearRegression = LinearRegression()
SimpleLinearRegression.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_predict= SimpleLinearRegression.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_predict))
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here, is there some other way to calculate accuracy score for regression? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: y = dataset.iloc[:,1].values shouldn't it be y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values?

Comment: @mamun, I think it's right. printing right values:print(X_test)
print(y_test)

Comment: I agree with @mamun : `X` will contain all but last column, while the target variable `y` is picket to be the second column, i.e. it is included in `X`. Depending on where your target variable really is you either need to change `X` or `y` slicing rule

Comment: On replacing X & y, I've the same problem yet........X = [[1.1],[1.3],[1.5],[2],[2.2],[2.9],[3],[3.2],[3.2],[3.7],[3.9],[4],[4],[4.1],[4.5],[4.9],[5.1],[5.3],[5.9],[6],[6.8],[7.1],[7.9],[8.2],[8.7],[9],[9.5],[9.6],[10.3],[10.5]]
#implement the dataset for train & test
y = [39343,46205,37731,43525,39891,56642,60150,54445,64445,57189,63218,55794,56957,57081,61111,67938,66029,83088,81363,93940,91738,98273,101302,113812,109431,105582,116969,112635,122391,121872]

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy as a metric is applicable to a **classification** problem, as it is defined as a fraction of labels that is correctly predicted. In your case you do a regression (`LinearRegression`), i.e. your target variable is continuous. So either you picked a wrong model my mistake or accuracy is a wrong metric for your problem.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. do we have some other accuracy metric for LinearRegression, any link would be a great help. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, see the `Regression` section of the list [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) for the pre-defined regression metrics. You can always define a custom metric that you fancy using [make_scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use mean absolute error and mean squared error.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
MAE = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_predict)
RMSE = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict))
```

Comment: it's giving me error:         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LeanerRegression.py", line 49, in <module>
    MAE = mean_absoute_error(y_test, y_predict)
NameError: name 'mean_absoute_error' is not defined

Comment: There’s a typo, I fixed it. But you should’ve been able to debug it. The traceback is pretty clear

Comment: So, it is giving me mean square error value, on my dataset it is printing : 3426.4269374307123, I'm sorry but can  I calculate accuracy with linear regression data.

Answer (score 1):

We can't use accuracy for regression problems, Its only used in classification problem.
You can use MSE,RMSE,MAPE,MAE as the matrix to determine how good your regression model is.

These values tell us how far we are from the correct predictions. The lower values are better for these cases.